# FFI and header files

Tags: import, ffi, nim-lang

This is my directory structure:

```
C:.
│   lodepng.h
│   lodepng.c
│   nim.cfg
│   test.png
│   util.nim
│
└───nimcache
```

util nim is importing a c function from lodepng.h like this:

```
proc loadPNG(image: var ptr[cchar], width, height: var cuint, filename: cstring)
  {.importc: "lodepng_decode32_file", header: "lodepng.h".}
```

But the header is not copied into nimcache nor is found when compiling the code. How can i make sure nim compiler uses it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution inside the nim [backend integration guide](http://nim-lang.org/docs/backends.html#nim-code-calling-the-backend-c-invocation-example):

```
{.compile: "lodepng.c".}
proc lodepng_decode32_file(image: var ptr[cchar], width, height: var cuint, filename: cstring): cuint {.importc.}
```